# SQLite insert throwing syntax exception

Tags: android, sqlite

**I am getting this error from SQLite,**

`near ",": syntax error (code 1):` , while compiling:

```
UPDATE OutfitItem 
SET outfit_img_relative_pos_x=?,clothing_item_ID=?,outfit_img_relative_pos_y=?,
outfit_img_relative_size_width=?,outfit_ID=?,outfit_img_relative_size_height=? 
WHERE (outfit_ID,clothing_item_ID) = (60,5)
```

**May someone spot the error for me please?**

**The following is the code which gets compiled...**

```
// ---updates a outfitItem---
        public boolean update(long outfitID, long clothingItemID, double imgRelativePos_X, double imgRelativePos_Y,
                double imgRelativeSize_width, double imgRelativeSize_height)
        {
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put(KEY_OUTFIT_ID, outfitID);
            args.put(KEY_CLOTHING_ITEM_ID, clothingItemID);
            args.put(KEY_OUTFIT_IMAGE_RELATIVE_POS_X, imgRelativePos_X);
            args.put(KEY_OUTFIT_IMAGE_RELATIVE_POS_Y, imgRelativePos_Y);
            args.put(KEY_OUTFIT_IMAGE_RELATIVE_SIZE_WIDTH, imgRelativeSize_width);
            args.put(KEY_OUTFIT_IMAGE_RELATIVE_SIZE_HEIGHT, imgRelativeSize_height);
            return db.update(TABLE_NAME, args, "(" + KEY_OUTFIT_ID + "," + KEY_CLOTHING_ITEM_ID + ") = (" + outfitID
                    + "," + clothingItemID + ")", null) > 0;
        }
```

**The following is the code which creates the table, and note that foreign keys is set to on...**

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "OutfitItem";

        public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_OUTFIT_ID
                + " int not null REFERENCES " + Table_Outfit.TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_OUTFIT_ID + ") ON DELETE CASCADE,"
                + KEY_CLOTHING_ITEM_ID + " int not null REFERENCES " + Table_ClothingItem.TABLE_NAME + "("
                + KEY_CLOTHING_ITEM_ID + ") ON DELETE CASCADE, " + KEY_OUTFIT_IMAGE_RELATIVE_POS_X + " real not null, "
                + KEY_OUTFIT_IMAGE_RELATIVE_POS_Y + " real not null, " + KEY_OUTFIT_IMAGE_RELATIVE_SIZE_WIDTH
                + " real not null, " + KEY_OUTFIT_IMAGE_RELATIVE_SIZE_HEIGHT + " real not null, " + "primary key ("
                + KEY_OUTFIT_ID + "," + KEY_CLOTHING_ITEM_ID + "));";
```

Comment: Someone please help soonest???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (outfit_ID,clothing_item_ID) = (60,5)
```

This is not valid SQL syntax. You need to use separate conditions with the `AND` conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

As *@Neil* rightly pointed out, use the following code and it would start working :

```
UPDATE OutfitItem 
SET outfit_img_relative_pos_x=?,clothing_item_ID=?,outfit_img_relative_pos_y=?,
outfit_img_relative_size_width=?,outfit_ID=?,outfit_img_relative_size_height=?
```

**`WHERE outfit_ID = 60 AND clothing_item_ID = 5;`**

Comment: No problem mate! Good luck ahead! :)